# Windows CMD - Find current baud rate of COM port

Tags: windows, powershell, serial-port, find, baud-rate

I am trying to parse the out put of `MODE` command in command prompt and assign it to a variable.
The out put of `mode` is as shown below,

```
PS C:\Users\test> mode %COMPORT%

Status for device COM5:
-----------------------
    Baud:            9600
    Parity:          None
    Data Bits:       8
    Stop Bits:       1
    Timeout:         OFF
    XON/XOFF:        OFF
    CTS handshaking: OFF
    DSR handshaking: OFF
    DSR sensitivity: OFF
    DTR circuit:     OFF
    RTS circuit:     OFF
```

I'm trying to get the first line using `FIND` as shown below,

```
mode COM5 | find /I "Baud"
```

it says `FIND: Parameter format not correct`

btw, this is how the whole code looks like,

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in (
    'REG QUERY HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM'
) do set "COMPORT=%%a" 
echo %COMPORT%

for /f "tokens=2" %%a in (
    'MODE %COMPORT% | FIND /I "Baud"'
) do set "SPEED=%%a" 
echo %SPEED%
```

But this is not working, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: but you want this as powershell code or as cmd code? not quite clear. In CMD what you're looking for is the `findstr /i` command https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html

Comment: It looks like the powershell console is treating this command diferently compared to the CMD. In normal command prompt this command runs fine, not in powershell console. btw, there is no need to use powershell console, but I got curious why it is failing!

Comment: This is the PowerShell equivalent: `'MODE %COMPORT% | Select-String "Baud"'` or `'MODE %COMPORT% | sls "Baud"'` cause I love alias :)

Comment: Or, without piping: `for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('MODE %COMPORT%') do if /i "%%a"=="baud:" set "speed=%%b"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventhough its still unknown to me why the same command works in a normal console but not in a powershell console, the problem with the script was entirely at a different place. Inside the `for` loop you need to escape the `|` character. It was not the `FIND` command's  `Parameter format not correct` error the real problem, (a false alarm), but the escaping needed for the `|`

Corrected script is as shown below.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in (
    'REG QUERY HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM'
) do set "COMPORT=%%a" 
echo %COMPORT%

for /f "tokens=2" %%a in (
    'MODE %COMPORT% ^| FIND /I "Baud"'
) do set "SPEED=%%a" 
echo %SPEED%
```